# How to write this C# method in java for android (apache client deprecated)?

Tags: java, c#, php, android, apache

I'm making an android version of my c# program and I need to convert this method to java considering that apache client was deprecated and I'm a newbie 
I'm using this method in c# to connect with a php file on my site using POST method to pass it user name and password then return result using echo
my C# code is

```
    protected string serverUrl = "http://soft.daiilydeal.com/soft.php";
    public static string UserName = "user";
    public static string Password = "password";

    private void frmRegister_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string response;
       new Thread(delegate(object t)
       {
           response = this.Submit(new string[] { "action", "login", "username", UserName, "password", Password });
           if (response == "allowed")
           {
               return;

           }
           else
           {
               this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
               {
                   this.Close();
               }));

               var action = MessageBox.Show("This copy of the software is not illegal", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);


           }
       }) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
   }
```

and this is the most important method

```
    private string Submit(string[] parameters)
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        string arg_0B_0 = string.Empty;
        string result;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.serverUrl);
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = 30000;
            byte[] array = new byte[0];
            string text = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i += 2)
            {
                text += string.Format("{0}={1}&", parameters[i], HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameters[i + 1]));
            }
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)text.Length;
            array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string text2 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            result = text2;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I searched but most answers use apache client and HttpURLConnction

Comment: you can still use the deprecated DefaultHttpClient but it is recommended to not to use deprecated classes , so you can use the HttpUrlConnection with AyncTask in Android. HttpUrlConnection for the REST services and AsyncTask so that all network calls are not made on the UI thread.

Comment: I don't know how to use HttpUrlConnection, I appreciate it if there is some tutorial for an example similar to what I need. thank you

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/
It is in Java, tell me if you can if you can convert this code to use it in android, if not , I will post the code in the answer